# Start new instance of job in sql server agent X minutes after last run was completed?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jobs, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

Is it possible to create a sql server job that will run an SSIS project (or any project) X minutes after the last instance was completed?

For example:
1) Run SSIS job for the first time at 3:10PM.
2) Job runs for 35 minutes.
3) Once job ends, restart job 5 minutes after it has completed.

We had something similar with Task Scheduler: Basically, it was set `Repeat Task every` 5 minutes with `Do not start a new instance`. This meant that the task would be executed 5 minutes after the previous job instance was completed and 2 instances would not run in parallel.

The reason I want to move to sql server agent is because today the task remained "Running" and the only way to stop it was to restart the server. That meant that all the other running jobs were affected. With sql server agent I have more control of the actual package.

Comment: You could have the last step of the job be to schedule the job again. See sp_add_schedule and sp_attach_schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Also if a job is already running and it's schedule tells it to run again it ignores the new request.